# Flatlist become undefined when calling item.images

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

The problem is that it says

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'image[0]')
```

This happens when I call my Flatlist

```
<FlatList
  numColumns={2}
  data={matches}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> chat(item)}>
      <CardItem
        image={item.images} // this is where the error is
        name={item.name}
        variant
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
/>
```

but when I console log my response from state (matches)
it shows that

```
[{"age": 21, "bio": "?", "height": "180", "id": 3, "images": [[Array]], "interest": [[Array]], "name": "JB Borja"]
```

The `data={matches}` shows the response above. 
But when I am calling the

```js
console.log(item.images)
```

It shows that it is undefined. When in fact there's a value inside the matches.

CardItem.js:

```
const CardItem = ({
  actions,
  description,
  image,
  uid,
  myId,
  name,
  onPressRight,
  onPressLeft,
  status,
  variant
}) => {
return (
    <View style={styles.containerCardItem}>
    <Image source={{uri: image[0][0] }} style={imageStyle} /> // this is where the error starts 
    <Text style={nameStyle}>{name}</Text>
);
```

Reason why I added image[0][0] is because the response of array is in this

> form: images:[ [url], [url] ].

I only needed to fetch the first image array. 
Even when I put console log in this const. I still get undefined. So the error isn't inside the CardItem.js; but rather where the flatlist is.

Comment: What is the initial value of `matches` in state? Please share entire component code.

Comment: @DrewReese I am using state hooks const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);

Comment: it could be because `images` is an array of arrays .. check on that... it could also be possible for that one of the item in the matches do not have items in the `images`  ... plz provide more info & full logs of matches (not sure what is present in `images` )..

Comment: What is `CardItem` doing with that `image` prop? Please share all relevant code. If the error is in `CardItem` you should share it.

Comment: @DrewReese it gets the image, then it displays it inside the card (same as cardview).